# Why's there discrepancies between file uploading via Postman and via the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I can't figure out why I'm getting this server error `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null` when trying to upload a file (POST request) to my endpoint when trying on the browser.

It works fine on Postman, I'm able to upload successfully.  Its just weird how I don't get the aforementioned error on Postman but I do get it when trying on the browser.  I believe my JS is off but I'm not too sure as I've tried everything under the sun to try to rectify this but no avail, I've hit a wall.

How can I rectify this?

**Note:** For more detail, here's a discrepancy I'm facing: When I `dd($request->all());` and submit the form on the browser - I get (which's incorrect):

```
array:1 [
   "userUpload" => []
]
```

When I do it on Postman - I get (which's correct):

```
array:1 [
  "userUpload" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#1325
    -test: false
    -originalName: "gallery12.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "/tmp"
    filename: "php4FMimY"
    basename: "php4FMimY"
    pathname: "/tmp/php4FMimY"
    extension: ""
    realPath: "/tmp/php4FMimY"
    aTime: 2022-01-20 19:42:45
    mTime: 2022-01-20 19:42:45
    cTime: 2022-01-20 19:42:45
    inode: 3146782
    size: 519395
    perms: 0100600
    owner: 1000
    group: 1000
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
]
```

Here's my JS:

```
const fileUpload = () => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8005/api/file-upload';

    let input = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]')

    let data = new FormData()
    data.append('file', input.files[0])

    const postData = {
        'userUpload' : input.files[0]
    }

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }

    // All of these are displaying the correct data
    console.log(authToken);
    console.log(postData);
    console.log(headers);

    axios.post(url, postData, {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

return (
    <form encType="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="userUpload" required/>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={fileUpload}>Upload!</Button>
    </form>
);
```

Here's FileUploadController.php:

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request)
    {

//        dd($request->all());
        $path = env('AWS_S3_PATH');
        $file = $request->file('userUpload');
        $imgName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $bucket = env('AWS_BUCKET');
        $region = env('AWS_REGION');
        $url = "https://{$bucket}.s3.{$region}.amazonaws.com{$path}{$imgName}";
        $userId = Auth::user()['UserID'];

        $file->storeAs(
            $path, // Folder
            $imgName, // Name of image
            's3' // Disk Name
        );

        $data = [
            'url' => $url,
            'UserID' => $userId,
            'isUploaded' => true,
            'timeStamp' => time(),
            'updated_at' => time()
        ];

        Upload::create($data);

        return $data;

    }
```

Comment: the user upload file is null. call it properly or find why its empty

Comment: @Dean but it's not empty.  If you see the comments above the `console.log()`s, it indicates that :)

Comment: Just to be clear are you saying that you only observe the error from adding the debug line or does it happen regardlesss?

Comment: @Sherif it happens regardless when trying on the browser.  I believe there's something with my JS but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Which thing happens regardless is then the pertenant question? Is it that the upload is failing?

Comment: @Sherif yeah exactly - the upload keeps on failing.  The server returns a 500 error all the time.

Comment: So most likely the upload fails on the server side for some reason. I'd start by checking error logs rather than using this particular approach to dwbugging the problem since it seems case specific.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the headers in your axios request are missing `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`.

Try this:

```js
const headers = {
    "Accept": 'application/json',
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    "Content-Type": 'multipart/form-data'
}
```